# how to increase request accept limit for asp classic

Tags: http, iis, asp-classic, http-post

from java applet I am sending post request to asp classic. I am sending a very large data in this request ,which is csv data, when number of character in this request increases and get more then 138000 then asp does not accept the request and java applet give 500 error, so can anybody tell me how can I increase the size limit of accept request of asp classic.

Answer (score 9):

Hard to say without knowing your server version.

If IIS6 you would change the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed property in the metabase (i think the default was 200KB on IIS6)

If IIS7, simply pop into Control Panel - Administrative Tools - IIS Admin & Click your site and expand it then click the ASP icon.

Expand the Limits Properties icon, and change the value in the “Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit” to a value larger than 200000 (which is about 200kb).

Comment: Is there any known risk to expanding this limit?

Comment: @JosephDoggie, just the usual: the bigger the limit, the easier it is for an attacker to cause undue load on your server, like causing it to run low on memory if the target page does load into memory the posted content.