# CSV is too large to be processed via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel, csv, vbscript

I'm having a problem when sending large amounts of data through an AJAX request. I'm pulling in an XLS file from a website and attempting to pass it through an API by parsing the data. I'm doing this in VBScript/Classic ASP so there is no native function to parse XLS so I'm first attempting to convert it to a CSV file through Javascript.

I'm using something called SheetJS (http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/) which is a great tool and it works just as I need it to. I can run an Excel file through it and it outputs the correct CSV data. I then try to send that data via AJAX to the ASP page with my code and I get a 500 error that I've isolated to being an issue with the file being too large. I was able to isolate to about 1652 lines of my Excel file and anything past that generates a CSV file too large to send.

All I am getting is a 500 error so I'm not really sure what else to do from this point. Is there a data limit on AJAX functions? Or is it a time limit type issue? I don't know how to find out which it is. Any suggestions on how to get a more detailed error message AND any fixes for this issue?

Comment: Maybe you're hitting the POST size limit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466081/how-to-increase-request-accept-limit-for-asp-classic

Comment: And when you get to the client, what are you going to do with this? You are going to probably run into another bottleneck once you get the server straightened out.

Comment: @epascarello, I'm saving the file to the server as a CSV. After that I will be parsing data but you're probably correct that it will cause problems being so large.

Answer (score -1):

While you can't work with .xls files natively in VBScript, there is ADO that makes it easy to do that via COM. This way scales well wrt memory. Start your research [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973/en-us).

Comment: I have no access to the server unfortunately. I'm working in the Volusion e-commerce framework and I can't alter anything. I'm assuming that's needed in order to do this?

Comment: @MxmastaMills - VBScript implies Windows, Windows should have ADO. But *I* don't know your systems.